# std::string::substr throws std::out_of_range but the arguments are in limit

Tags: c++, string, substr, outofrangeexception

I have a vector of strings:

```
vector<string> tokenTotals;
```

When `push_back` is called, a string of length 41 is stored and I must operate on each element of my vector and get two substrings, the first in range 0 to 28 and the second in range 29 to 36:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tokenTotals.size(); i++)
{
    size_t pos = tokenTotals[i].find(": ");
    cout << tokenTotals[i] << endl; // Show all strings - OK
    cout << tokenTotals[i].length() << endl; // Lenght: 41
    string first  = tokenTotals[i].substr(0, 28); // OK
    string second = tokenTotals[i].substr(29, 36); // ERROR
    cout << first << " * " << second << endl;
}
```

But when I try to get the second substring, I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of std::out_of_range.
what():: basic_string::substr
```

Any idea of what could have happened?

Answer (score 11):

See the [`std::string::substr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). The second parameter is the **length** of the substring, **not the position** of the character after the substring, so the result is an attempt to access elements out of range -`std::out_of_range` is thrown.

With `tokenTotals[i].substr(0, 28)` this mistake doesn't manifest, since the substring has both size and the position one past end 28.

Answer (score 7):

```
substr(29,36);
```

will attempt to get a string that starts at position 29 and has a **size** of 36 characters. Unfortunately 29 + 36 > 41

[documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)