# C++ Terminate has called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: c++

I have tried countless times to solve this and nothing on the internet is helping.  I've figured that the problem is with the "getline(cin,strg);" but i dont know what, the program runs perfectly if I just use "cin >> strg;", however, i want to account for spaces and whatnot. What is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza";
string alphacap = "AbcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzA";
int loc;

string code(string str) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length()-1; i++){
        if(alphabet.find(str[i]) != str.npos){
            loc = alphabet.find(str[i]);
            str = str.substr(0,i) + alphacap[loc+1] + str.substr(i+1,str.length());
        }
    }
    return str;
}

string decode(string str) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length()-1; i++){
        if(alphabet.find(str[i]) != str.npos){
            loc = alphabet.find(str[i]);
            str = str.substr(0,i) + alphacap[loc-1] + str.substr(i+1,str.length());
        }
    }
    return str;
}


int main() {
    string codc;
    do{
        system("cls");
        cout << "Code or Decode? ";
        cin >> codc;
    }while(codc != "code" and codc != "Code" and codc != "decode" and codc != "Decode");

    string str;

    if(codc == "code" or codc == "Code"){
        string strg;
        getline(std::cin,strg);
        cout << code(strg);
    }else{
        string strg;
        getline(cin,strg);
        cout << decode(strg);
    }

}
```

Comment: What to do you want to count? Also, which is the input you are giving?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by:

```
str.substr(i + 1, str.length());
```

as it tries to access `str`'s elements up to `i + str.length()`. This fails for `i > 0`. See the original [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318770/stdstringsubstr-throws-stdout-of-range-but-the-arguments-are-in-limit/32318799#32318799).

<sup>`str.substr(i + 1, str.length() - i - 1);` would correct it.</sup>

If you want to get the part of the string on the right of the index `i`, you can just **leave out the second argument**:

```
str.substr(i + 1);
```

See the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

And this is dangerous too:

```
alphacap[loc + 1]
alphacap[loc - 1]
```

What if `loc` is the index of the first/last element in `alphacap`?

Comment: I fixed what you said the problem was and it's still giving me trouble. Why does it work when i use "cin >> strg"?

Comment: @Deck I can't say without knowing what the input is in both cases.

Comment: every input seems to work. Lets just say it's "Hello world"

Comment: @Deck Your code obviously can't handle spaces. It requires each character be a letter.

Answer (score 0):

After `getline(std::cin,strg)`   strg=="".
 
In loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= str.length()-1; i++)
```

comparison  <= not work correct if str.length() ==0.
 
After changing to

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (int)str.length()-1; i++)
```

program not fail.
 
Preferable also change 
    `cin >> codc;`
to
    `getline(cin,codc);`

Now program not fail.